# how to store data in specific format? in WYSWYG?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using WYSIWYG window 4 taking input from user, so he can enter font Bold, Italic etc. How to store such data, so that when I display on some other page, same font styles and formats comes back??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WYSIWYG is nothing but a Div tag with "Contenteditable" attribute, which will help capture bold, italic etc. and the content you see is rendered version of the html.

if you want to get the HTML just get the innerHTML of the contenteditable div it will give you html code. let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a class called `FontMetadata`, and store the data in a tuple like

```
Tuple<Data, DataStyle>
```